# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode9

[SCREEN SHOT OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvVoN.png)

I have been trying to resolve this error for a couple of days. It is a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The link is a picture of the code.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint. The crash is not related to `AppDelegate`

Comment: 1) Show anything relevant printed in the debug console.  2) Add a breakpoint for Swift errors so that the debugger shows you better information.

Answer (score 2):

`SIGABRT` happens when you call an `outlet` that is not there.

- No view is connected
- Duplicate might be there

Outlets are references to `storyboard/xib`-based UI elements inside your `view controller`. Make sure whatever you are trying to call is there.