# Extremely simple Swift signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift

[image: Silly app]

I fail to understand why my app is giving me a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error.

I basically have a text field that I only want to be numbers, do a calculation when the button is pressed an put it in the other label. 
I had more code around it with more boxes and buttons and simplified it to this and it still doesn't work!

Thank you!

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete error (as text) being shown in the debugger console. You are only showing the least important tail end of it in your screenshot.

Comment: hi, I just realized that my answer went unnoticed. was it useful?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check the following thread: [Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912413/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-in-xcode-9/46912654#46912654)

Quoting from my answer:

> `SIGABRT` happens when you call an `outlet` that is not there.
>
> - No view is connected
> - Duplicate might be there
>
> Outlets are references to `storyboard/xib`-based UI elements inside
>   your `view controller`. Make sure whatever you are trying to call is
>   there.